# substitution of same variable in context-free grammars

Tags: automata, finite-automata, context-free, logic

[image]

Above is a theorem coming from the book "Formal languages and automata" by Peter Linz concerning substitution of variables.
Could someone explain why A and B have to be different variables?

Comment: What do you mean by A and B are different variable? Please elaborate more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspect probably, theorem 6.1 still holds even if $A$ and $B$ are the same variable. This can be seen by following the proof of the theorem, assuming $B$ is $A$.

So, it is not correct to say "it is necessary that $A$ and $B$ be different variables" so that the conclusion $L(\widehat G) = L(G)$ holds. The quoted text is from the text right after the proof of that theorem in that textbook.

However, when $A$ and $B$ are the same variable, the change from $G$ to $\widehat G$ is unlikely to be helpful to simplify a context-free grammar by any reasonable measure.  In order to simplify a context-free grammar, we would most probably use theorem 6.1 in the case when $A$ and $B$ are different variables, if we want to use it at all.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Would you also like to take a look at my other question here?https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/152524/variable-repetitions-in-pumping-lemma-for-context-free-languages